# Gestouch is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, gestures, starling-framework

I use starling for book reader app. When i change the book, i'm disposing the current starling and create new starling instance.But when I created new starling, Gestouch doesn't works.

How to restart gestouch for a new starling instance

**gestouch code:**

```
    gallery.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,book);

    onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK )
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            this.starling.stop();
            this.starling.dispose();
            this.starling = null;
        }
    }

    book(e:MouseEvent):void
    { 
        this.starling = new Starling(RacTestApp,stage,viewPort);
        Gestouch.inputAdapter ||= new NativeInputAdapter(stage);
        Gestouch.addDisplayListAdapter(starling.display.DisplayObject, new StarlingDisplayListAdapter());
        Gestouch.addTouchHitTester(new StarlingTouchHitTester(this.starling), -1);
        this.starling.start();
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys I got the answer:

```
OnKeydown(){
    Gestouch.removeTouchHitTester(this.myStarlingTouchHitTester);
}

book(){
    this.myStarlingTouchHitTester = new StarlingTouchHitTester(this.starling);
    Gestouch.addTouchHitTester(this.myStarlingTouchHitTester, -1);
}
```

We have to add and remove `TouchHitTester`, if we are using multiple starling instances.